# Question with accepted answer which isn't relevant now

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Today I answered [What is the maximum iframe width of a facebook page? (July 2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828293/maximum-iframe-width-july-2011), but before posting an answer, as always, I searched for duplicates. I found [Facebook - Maximum iframe width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655390/facebook-maximum-iframe-width)  with an accepted answer, which was correct the day the question was asked. Because of the changes in Facebook platform, that answer isn't correct anymore, and I think the OP of the question I answered also found that question, and asked a new question. This could be seen by title that he put to his question, "Maximum iframe width? (July 2011)". That's why I answered his question with information relevant today.

What is a common practice in cases like this?
Should I edit old question, adding correct answer, should I indicate somehow that there a question with relevant answer?
Should they be merged in one question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the correct answer is fundamentally different in each question, I submit that *they are not exact duplicates.*  The original question was "What is the maximum iframe width for a Facebook application in October 2009?", and the new question is "What is the maximum iframe width for a Facebook application today?"

I've closed the original question as "Too Localized."

Comment: But why would anyone care about the iframe width for a Facebook app two years ago? Historical curiosity?

Comment: @Justin: That's an argument for getting rid of the old question, not marking the new question as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: Good point, but in a case of "getting rid of the old question", there should be some mechanism which give ability to delete question without losing the rep for the users who earned it on those questions.

Comment: And I think "Too Localized" could be not enough, or not clear. I like idea of gensis, that there should be some note(link) to new question. For users who land that page from google or other search results.

Comment: I've added a link to the old question and locked it.

Comment: yes that block with a link is exactly what I was thinking about. Hope notes like this will become common practice for the obsolete questions

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an answer to the previous question, reporting that the accepted answer is not anymore, and explaining what the actual situation is. This would help who read [Facebook - Maximum iframe width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655390/facebook-maximum-iframe-width) and let them know the situation is changed.

Answers are not only thought for who asks the question, but for every user who reads the questions.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this should be changed in old answer, new question should be answered too, with being marked as duplicated and commented with text like "possible duplicate:  <- max width has been changed, so old answer is edited and is correct now"